# Getting a 403 Forbidden when trying to call MyEtherAPI with Nethereum

Tags: json-rpc, nethereum

Don't know what's wrong. Here's the code:

```
let web3 = Web3("https://api.myetherapi.com:443")
let balanceTask = web3.Eth.GetBalance.SendRequestAsync(account.PublicAddress, 1)
balanceTask.Wait()
balanceTask.Result.ToString()
```

The API I'm using is https://www.myetherapi.com/ (it works with CURL!).

The exception is:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
 ---> EdjCase.JsonRpc.Client.RpcClientUnknownException: Error occurred when trying to send rpc requests(s)
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at EdjCase.JsonRpc.Client.RpcClient.<SendAsync>d__23`2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at EdjCase.JsonRpc.Client.RpcClient.<SendAsync>d__23`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at EdjCase.JsonRpc.Client.RpcClient.<SendRequestAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Nethereum.JsonRpc.Client.RpcRequestResponseHandler`1.<SendRequestAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at GWallet.Backend.AccountApi.GetBalance(Account account) in C:\Users\andre_000\Documents\Code\gwallet\src\GWallet.Backend\AccountApi.fs:line 19
---> (Inner Exception #0) EdjCase.JsonRpc.Client.RpcClientUnknownException: Error occurred when trying to send rpc requests(s) ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at EdjCase.JsonRpc.Client.RpcClient.<SendAsync>d__23`2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at EdjCase.JsonRpc.Client.RpcClient.<SendAsync>d__23`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at EdjCase.JsonRpc.Client.RpcClient.<SendRequestAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Nethereum.JsonRpc.Client.RpcRequestResponseHandler`1.<SendRequestAsync>d__7.MoveNext()<---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that by using `web3.Eth.GetBalance` API I would already be using the `https://api.myetherapi.com/eth` endpoint instead of the root `https://api.myetherapi.com`, but I was wrong, I had to use the former URL.